# Обойти все теги с src

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Помогите составить регулярное выражение(если это возможно) чтобы сделать найти все теги с src и добавить к уже имеющимся значениям что-то ещё. 
Пример:

> img src='1'

AFTER

> img src='path/1'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$string=preg_replace("/src\s?=\s?(['\"])(\w+)/iu", "src=\$1вставка\$2", $string);
```

Comment: <iframe src="source.html"></iframe>

Comment: `<?php
$string = "<iframe src=\"source.html\"></iframe> bla bla bla src='oops' src=\"motherfucker\"";
echo htmlspecialchars(preg_replace("/src=['\"](\w+)/iu", "src=\"вставка\$1", $string));
?>`  => `<iframe src="вставкаsource.html"></iframe> bla bla bla src="вставкаoops' src="вставкаmotherfucker"`

Comment: Я так понял автору именно `img` нужно, хотя теперь перечетав вопрос уверенности нету )) мой первый коммент был к тому, что `iframe` не должен попадать под замену как раз

Comment: А зачем в вашем варианте группировка `$1`? В которую между прочем не входит `http://`, `//`, `.html` или `.jpg` и т.п.

Comment: Я программист и прочитал всё как написано -  найти все теги с src и добавить к уже имеющимся значениям что-то ещё

Comment: я то же, поэтому конкретный пример с `img` в вопросе меня в другую сторону увел )

Comment: Правильно. Именно любые теги. Img как пример.

Answer (score 0):

Если нужно именно заменить и именно у тегов `img`, то можно так:

```
$str = '<body>
   <img src="photo1.jpg" />
   <img class="pic" data-myattr="id100500" src="/PHOTO2.jpg">
</body>';
$result = preg_replace("/(<img[a-z0-9\"'= -]+src=['|\"])\/?([a-z0-9\.\/]+)/i", "$1http://mysite.com/$2", $str);
echo $result;
```

P.S.:Мне интересно, люди совсем обленились? Вы хоть что-то сделали для решения СВОЕЙ проблемы?

Comment: Опыта для работы с регулярками очень мало. Все сводится к [a-z0-9].В интернете ничего не накопал. Учусь да и горит найти решение быстрее. Простите)